# Is it possible to create dynamic proxies without having base class or interface?

Tags: c#, .net, castle-dynamicproxy, dynamic-proxy

Is it possible to create a dynamic proxy using common libraries like `Castle Dynamic Proxy` without having any base class or interface? I'm indeed interested to have dynamic on-the-fly classes in run-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, use Reflection.Emit to bake your interface, then pass the generated interface type to `CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget` and provide interceptors.

Just keep in mind that you cannot unload a type, only an appdomain, so if you are going to create thousands of types you might end-up in a world of hurt performance-wise.